# IEEE 754 double-precision numbers from MIPS C to Java conversion

Tags: java, c, floating-point, pic, ieee-754

I have a PIC32 embedded microcontroller running the C32 compiler.  I'm sending a UDP packet containing a 64-bit double value to a Java program.  In my test, I'm trying to send the decimal value 40.5 to Java.

I would expect to receive:
0x4044400000000000

since
System.out.println(Double.longBitsToDouble(0x4044400000000000L));

prints:
40.5

If I send the UDP packet without any conversions, I'm receiving:
0x00002242352D3330

Any idea how I can get this value into Java?  I can't make heads or tails of the C32 representation of the double.

Comment: Is sizeof(double) actually 8 on the PIC? How are you calling htonl on the double?

Comment: how are you pulling this in to java?

Comment: @Collin Yes, sizeof(double) is 8 on the pic32

Comment: @dbrank0, endianness is little on the MIPS and BIG in Java.

Comment: @Scott, In Java, I'm dumping the raw bytes I receive.  I've tried using Double.longBitsToDouble as well as DataInputStream.readDouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PIC32 is little endian.  A `double` is represented by 64 bits, and a `long` is 32 bits.  For 64 bits, you need a `long long`.

`htonl()` takes a `long`, as noted above.  You are truncating it with the cast, and after endianness conversion, you are getting the shown results.

I found this in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/g1FFFFpU); it's macro that should work for converting your 64 bit `long long`:

```
#define htonll(x) \
((((x) & 0xff00000000000000LL) >> 56) | \
(((x) & 0x00ff000000000000LL) >> 40) | \
(((x) & 0x0000ff0000000000LL) >> 24) | \
(((x) & 0x000000ff00000000LL) >> 8) | \
(((x) & 0x00000000ff000000LL) << 8) | \
(((x) & 0x0000000000ff0000LL) << 24) | \
(((x) & 0x000000000000ff00LL) << 40) | \
```

Comment: useful. so htonl is truncating some of my data.  I also found a struct packing issue that I've eliminated as well.  The question has been updated with the actual data I'm now sending and now receiving.

Comment: +1 since this is useful and could be run in java or on the PIC

Comment: This macro becomes more useful if it's wrapped in something like `#if LITTLE_ENDIAN ... #else #define htonll(x) x #endif`.  Because then you have portable code.

Comment: It looks like I need to do some manual packaging to ensure that the number sent is IEEE-754.  I found this website that had a pack754_64 function. [link]http://bit.ly/Ica9xV[/link].  Once I combined that with your htonll, I ended up with 0x4044400000000000 on both ends of the wire and 40.5 on both ends. :)  `u64_t value_to_send = htonll(pack754_64((double)40.5));`

Answer (score 1):

`htonl()` takes a `long`, not a `double`.